# x86 Non-Temporal Instructions: Is fencing ever needed for thread-local data?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, memory-barriers

On x86/x64, non-temporal store instructions such as `MOVNTI` and `MOVNTPS` make weaker memory ordering guarantees than "regular" stores.  I understand fences (e.g. `SFENCE`) are necessary when sharing memory that will be written to non-temporally across threads.  However, are fence instructions ever necessary for thread-local memory?  If I write to a location via `MOVNTPS`, is the write guaranteed to be visible to subsequent instructions in the same thread without any fence instruction?

Comment: A single thread **always** observes its *own* actions in program order.  The cardinal rule of out-of-order CPUs is that they always behave as if your code ran in program order.  (The only exception is when the architecture has other rules: e.g. IA-64 was an experiment in explicit parallelism, where each VLIW block of instructions executed in parallel.  So you could do a swap with `{ a=b, b=a }` in the same block of instructions or something.  I guess the branch-delay slot in some RISC architectures is another example.)

Comment: There probably aren't ISAs where single-threaded code needs to fence anything.  Cores can snoop their own store buffers pretty easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they will be visible without fences. See section *8.2.2 Memory Ordering in P6 and More Recent Processor Families* in the *Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 3A: System Programming Guide, Part 1* which says, among others:

> for memory regions defined as write-back cacheable, [...]
>   Reads may be reordered with older writes to different locations but
>   not with older writes to the same location.

and

> Writes to memory are not reordered with other writes, with the
>   following exceptions:
>   -- streaming stores (writes) executed with the non-temporal move instructions
>       (MOVNTI, MOVNTQ, MOVNTDQ, MOVNTPS, and MOVNTPD);